# minimum internet speed required to access the remote app

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remoteapp

I have published a remote app using the remote desktop service and many users are using the application. is there any benching mark for the minimum internet speed required to access the remote app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that no, there is not a  clear benchmark. The reason is because RDP connection min requirements depends on many things:

1) **the RDP protocol version** - newer versions of the protocol support different encodings of the data that is transmitted

2) **the app that is ran** - the amount of data is different if playing a sound / video vs having Excel open and not doing anything

3) **the hardware on both client and server** - as mentioned, different versions need to do hardware encoding / decoding. The RDP protocol is trying to self-adjust and get the best level for your current status (see the network bar at the top)

4) **other network attributes** (i.e.: packet loss, number of hops etc.) - you might have a really fast internet connection to Google, but not to your RDP server. Even then, you might be on wireless, so while you have 100Mbps at the router, you will have packet loss.

5) **other ad-hoc factors**